# Convert an associative array into an associative array which has a key with another associative array as its value in php

Tags: php, for-loop

**I have an associative array $data:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [emp_id] => 1
    [emp_name] => Emp1
    [emp_email] => emp1@example.com
    [dep_id] => 1
    [dep_name] => Mario
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [emp_id] => 1
    [emp_name] => Emp1
    [emp_email] => emp1@example.com
    [dep_id] => 2
    [dep_name] => Tony
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
    [emp_id] => 2
    [emp_name] => Emp2
    [emp_email] => emp2@example.com
    [dep_id] => 3
    [dep_name] => Jack
  )
)
```

**I want to convert this array into an associative array with the 'dependent' as an associative array with two fields `dep_name` and `dep_id` field like this:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [emp_id] => 1
    [emp_name] => Emp1
    [emp_email] => emp1@example.com
    [dependant] => [
      [
        [dep_id] => 1
        [dep_name] => Mario
      ]
      [
        [dep_id] => 2
        [dep_name] => Tony
      ]
    ]
)
[1] => Array
(
  [emp_id] => 2
  [emp_name] => Emp2
  [emp_email] => emp2@example.com
  [dependant] => [
    [
        [dep_id] => 3
        [dep_name] => Jack
    ]
  )
)
```

**I tried using this way:**

```
$newEmployeeInfo = [];
$newEmployeeKey = [];
$newDependantInfo = [];
$newKey = 0;
foreach($data as $dataKey => $dataValue){
   if(!in_array($dataValue["emp_id"],$newEmployeeKey)){
       ++$newKey;
       $newEmployeeInfo[$newKey]["emp_id"] = $dataValue["emp_id"];
       $newEmployeeInfo[$newKey]["emp_name"] = $dataValue["emp_name"];
       $newEmployeeInfo[$newKey]["emp_email"] = $dataValue["emp_email"];
   }                
   $newEmployeeInfo[$newKey]["dependant"][$dataKey] = $dataValue[$newDependantInfo];       
       $newDependantInfo[$newKey]["dep_id"] = $dataValue["dep_id"];
       $newDependantInfo[$newKey]["dep_name"] = $dataValue["dep_name"];                         
       ];                       
 }
```

I was able to create the associative array with the keys `emp_id`, `emp_name` and `emp_email` with the respective values, but was unable to push `dep_id` and `dep_name` into the "dependant" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($data as $key => $value){
   $newArr[$value['emp_id']]['emp_id'] = $value['emp_id'];
   $newArr[$value['emp_id']]['emp_name'] = $value['emp_name'];
   $newArr[$value['emp_id']]['emp_email'] = $value['emp_email'];
   $newArr[$value['emp_id']]['dependant'][] = [
       'dep_id'=>$value['dep_id'],
       'dep_name'=>$value['dep_name']
    ];
}
```

also maybe you need to reindex the array as index will be emp_id in new arr

Note: i haven't tested code.